# ERROR MYSQL AL ESTABELCER DOS FK

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

El problema se presenta que cuando yo establezco la fk del campo nick_name de user me da el siguiente error como que está fuera de indice.
Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'nick_name_user_fk' in the referenced table 'usuario'  0.000 sec

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS torneo_futbolin;
CREATE DATABASE torneo_futbolin;
USE torneo_futbolin;

CREATE TABLE usuario(
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    nick_name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    mail VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    avatar VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE administrador(
    id_user INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    nick_name_user  VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT id_user_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES usuario(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT nick_name_user_fk FOREIGN KEY (nick_name_user) REFERENCES usuario(nick_name)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_user)
);
```

Comment: El error te dice que nick_name no es clave, y tiene razon.. en teeoria, podrias repetir ese valor todas las veces que quieras. Igual, no deberias referenciar a ese campo, si no al campo Id, siempre.. mira si alguien quiere cambiar su nick???

Comment: Aparte del error, es extraño que una tabla se llame `administrador`. ¿Esa tabla no debería ser una columna en tu tabla `usuario`, por ejemplo, una columna a través de la cual identifiques el rol (admnistrador, lector, editor, etc? Por lo general un `administrador` no es otra cosa que un tipo de usuario.

Comment: Lo que tratas de hacer parece un poco raro. El usario tiene un nick_name. Y un administrador tiene una referencia a un usuario. Pero esto no te basta. El administrador también tiene un nick_name. Okay, el administrador tiene un nick_name y su usario tiene un nick_name también, y estos nombres pueden ser iguáles o diferentes. Pero adémas quieres añadir un constraint que el nick_name del administrador ocurre en la tabla usario. Esto parece muy raro. El usario puede tener el nick_name Joe, y el administrador el nick_name Jack, pero solamente si hay otro usario con el nick_name Jack. ¿Por qué?

Comment: Puede, que lo que *realmente* quieres hacer es remover el nick_name de la tabla administrador, así que el nick_name del administrador  simpre es el nick_name de su usario. :-)

Answer (score 0):

La creación de la clave externa en la tabla administrador es el error que estás cometiendo. El mensaje de error indica que en la tabla referenciada `'usuario'` no se encuentra un índice para la restricción `'nick_name_user_fk'`.

El problema radica en que intentaste establecer una clave externa en el campo `nick_name_user` de la tabla administrador, pero no creaste un índice en el campo correspondiente de la tabla usuario. Las claves externas deben referirse a una columna de la tabla que contiene un índice.

Para solucionar esto, puede agregar un índice a la columna `nick_name` de la tabla usuario. Aquí está la alteración que debes hacer:

```
CREATE TABLE usuario(
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    nick_name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    mail VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    avatar VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    INDEX (nick_name)  -- Agrega este índice
);

CREATE TABLE administrador(
    id_user INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    nick_name_user  VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT id_user_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES usuario(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT nick_name_user_fk FOREIGN KEY (nick_name_user) REFERENCES usuario(nick_name)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_user)
);
```

Al incluir **INDEX (nick_name)** en la definición de la tabla usuario, crea un índice en el campo `nick_name`, lo que permite que la clave externa de la tabla administrador haga referencia an este índice. Esto debería resolver tu problema.
Espero haberte ayudado Andrea.